# List Only Child Categories Related to Entries

Tags: entries, category, relatedto

**I need to show a list of Child Categories which only have Entries attached.**

From about 6 different solutions here, I have assembled the following. It works perfectly on a Section that has < 200 Entries with a Category Group that contains 50 Parent Cats that each may have up to 10 Child Cats.

My concern is that with a larger Section (3,200 entries, yet to be imported into Craft) it will break down, timeout, etc. because in order for this to work, ALL the Entries from a Section must be present in the Array for the Categories to check Relations against.

For brevity and clarity, the following URL structure is required by the client for several reasons...

```
URL = /alpha/yadda/news
syntax = /[parent-category]/identifier/[section]

Section = News
Category Group = 1
Category Examples =
alpha
    alpha-1
    alpha-2
    alpha-3
beta
    beta-1
    beta-2
    beta-3
    beta-4
etc....
```

Based on that, here is what I've assembed that works great for 200 entries in News. It outputs a list of Child categories that only have News entries, based on the Parent's Category Slug in segment 1:

```
{# 1. find ALL the entry ids for a channel #}
{% set entryIds = craft.entries.section('news').limit(null).ids() %}

{# 2. find all the cats in Group 1 related to those entries #}
{% set categories = craft.categories.relatedTo({ sourceElement: entryIds }).groupId(1).limit(null).find() %}

{# 3. set var from URL seg1 and use to get CatModel Object: catParent #}
{% set parentSlug = craft.request.getSegment(1) %}
{% set catParent = craft.categories.slug(parentSlug).first() %}

{# 4. using catParent, get child cats #}
{% set subCategories = craft.categories.descendantOf(catParent) %}

{# 5. loop through cats found matching entries in step 2 
        then subloop through this Parent Cat's descendants for match #}
{% for category in categories %}
    {% set currentCat = category.title %}
    {% for subCat in subCategories %}
        {% if subCat.title == currentCat %}
            <li>{{ subCat.title }}</li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Again, this all works...for 200 entries in News. But I don't see how it's scalable for the 3,200 blog entries that will be imported.

**Just seems like there must be a better, more efficient way to display a list of Categories (or only descendants of a specific Parent Cat) that have Entries attached?**

Answer (score 1):

Having the need for a similar setup to yourself, I came up with a more efficient example below.

```
{% set entryIds = craft.entries.section('news').status('live').limit(null).ids() %}

{% set parentSlug = craft.request.getSegment(1) %}
{% set catParent = craft.categories.slug(parentSlug).first() %}

{% set categories = craft.categories.relatedTo({ sourceElement: entryIds }).groupId(1).limit(null).descendantOf(catParent).find() %}

{% nav category in categories %}
    <li>
        <a href="#">{{ category.title }}</a>
        {% ifchildren %}
            <ul>
                {% children %}
            </ul>
        {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
{% endnav %}
```

Comment: This is awesome! I no longer work on the original project for which I posted this, but I hope your much better solution helps others!